# How to schedule a MySQL database backup of one table per file in Windows?

Tags: mysql, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, backup

I'm using MySQL Server 5.5 and need to schedule a daily database backup.
Am currently doing the following in a batch file:

```
set currdate=%date:~4%
Set FileDate=%currdate:/=_%

mysqldump -u root-proot db > "C:\backup\database\db%FileDate%.sql"
```

It exports all tables in a single file. I want to export one file per table.

Comment: Isn't `mysqldump -T [dir_name]` option working for you? You get separate structure (.sql) and data (.txt) files, but still easy to import...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following outputs all table names to a temporary file first and then iterates through them, dumping each one to an appropriately named file:

```
@echo off
set currdate=%date:~4%
set filedate=%currdate:/=_%
mysql --skip-column-names -u root -proot db -e "show tables;" > tables.tmp
for /f "skip=3 delims=|" %%t in (tables.tmp) do (
  mysqldump -u root -proot db %%t > "C:\backup\database\db_%%table_%filedate%.sql"
)
del tables.tmp
```

Comment: Neha -- is this not adequate?  (I'm wondering why the belated Bounty.)

Comment: I would like to point out that the index parameter name of %%table is invalid in a loop because the loop parameter name must be a single character.  Therefore use %%t instead of %%table.  I confirmed this on Windows Server 2016.  Perhaps other versions of windows allow longer parameter names?

Comment: @Vincent Thanks for pointing it out - haven't come across this before and not sure which Windows versions it applies to (was working for me in 2018, guessing that was on Windows 8.1). Have now updated the answer to use `%%t` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not indicated what is wrong with the answer provided, here's a similar answer, *(please note that this is completely untested)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem modify as necessary
Set "buDest=C:\backup\database"
Set "dbName=db"
Set "dbPass=root"
Set "dbUser=root"
Rem If binaries are not in %CD% or %PATH% modify the Set line below
Rem     Example: Set "sqlBin=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
Set "sqlBin=."

Set "dStamp="
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null') Do If Not Defined dStamp Set "dStamp=%%A_%%B_%%C"

If Not Exist "%buDest%\" MD "%buDest%" 2>Nul || Exit /B

"%sqlBin%\mysql" --user=%dbUser% --password=%dbPass% -D %dbName% -Bse "Show Tables";|^
 For /F "Skip=3 Delims=| " %%A In ('FindStr "^|"') Do (
    mysqldump --user=%dbuser% --password=%dbpass% %%A >"%buDest%\%dbName%-%%A-%dStamp%.sql")
```

*Just ensure that the value data on lines `3`, `4`, `5`, `6` and possibly `9` is modified as necessary*